# The value of the variable doesn't change after calling it in before each?

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I am testing with Jasmine and I came across the spy implementation.

I  have this piece of code:

```
describe("A spy", function() {
  let foo;
  let bar = null;

  beforeEach(function() {
    foo = {
      setBar: function(value) {
        bar = value;
      }
    };
    spyOn(foo, 'setBar');
    foo.setBar(123);
    foo.setBar(456, 'another param');
    console.log(bar)
  });

  it("tracks all the arguments of its calls", function() {
    expect(foo.setBar).toHaveBeenCalledWith(123);
    expect(foo.setBar).toHaveBeenCalledWith(456, 'another param');
    expect(bar).toBeNull(); /* Why is this NULL it should be 456 because it the last value we called our function with!!!*/
  });
});
```

I have add this comment `/* Why is this NULL it should be 456 !!!*/` just to clarify what I don't understand.
Because this code:

```
let bar1 = null
let foo1 = {
      setBar: function(value) {
        bar1 = value;
      }
    }
     foo1.setBar(123);
    foo1.setBar(456, 'another param');
    console.log(bar1) // 456
```

prints `456`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you enabled `spyOn` on a function (here foo.setBar) is called, by default jasmine will not call the actual function, it will just track the details.

If you want to call the actual function you have to specify `spyOn(foo, 'setBar').and.callThrough();` instead of just `spyOn(foo, 'setBar')`.

Thereafter you can observe that `expect(bar).toBeNull()` will fail and `expect(bar).toBe(456)` will succeed.